# Creating a horizontal separator in xamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics, separator, xamdatagrid

I want some way of indicating a separation or line between two records whose dataitems are known, in a XamDataGrid. Currently I'm doing this by adding a background brush to the rows that contains a gradient (the top row has solid red near the bottom, the bottom row has solid red near the top), resulting in the appearance of a nice-looking red line between the two rows. A converter checks the dataitems against fields containing the special dataitems, and if they match, it applies the brush. However, now I need to add actual backgrounds to the rows.

[image: sample run, showing the red line needed, along with an example of a normal background (yellow)]

So is there a way to apply two LinearGradientBrushes to the same row? Alternatively, I tried adding the StopCollections for the two border gradients to the normal background brushes, but this means for every normal background, there's 3 possible brushes (simple, red at top, red at bottom), which quickly adds up when you have 12 possible backgrounds.

On a different tangent, is it maybe possible to add a line or show a separator in a xamDataGrid in any other way than this background hack? Maybe a border hack or an actual way to insert visual elements into the grid at a location specified by row indexes?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a style for the DataRecordCellArea to show the border below the cells.  For example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
</Style>
```

Note that you would still need to add the logic that you have to use this conditionally.